# How to use regular expressions in python to split articles based on punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I need to divide the article into sentences by punctuation. I use the following regular expression:

```
re.split(r'[,|.|?|!]', strContent)
```

It does work, but there is a problem. It will separate the following Latin names that should not be split (such as G. lucidum):

```
Many studies to date have described the anticancer properties of G. lucidum,
```

The abbreviation of this Latin name is a capital letter followed by a dot and a space.
So I try to modify the above regular expression as follows:

```
re.split(r'[,|(?:[^A-Z].)|?|!]', strContent)
```

However, the following error prompt was received:

```
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

How can I modify this regular expression?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `[]` and `()` in regular expressions.

Comment: You don't want to treat a full stop after a capital letter as the end of the sentence? What if it's something like "I watched the TV."?

Comment: @Barmar yes. Because the articles I deal with are biomedical documents. And I just don't want to split in the case of only one capital letter followed by a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and put it *before* the character set that matches the sentence ending.

The negative lookbehind should match a word that's just a single capital letter. This can be done by matching a word boundary before the letter with `\b`.

You also don't need `|` inside the character set. That's used for alternative patterns to match.

```
re.split(r'(?<!\b[A-Z])[,.?!]', strContent)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efficient and powerful answer.

Comment: This fails for abbreviations which end in lowercase letter, e.g. `Dr. Who was a villain.`

Answer (score 1):

Using pure regex to find complete sentences is difficult, because of edge cases such as abbreviations, which you have been seeing.  You should use an NLP library like NLTK instead.

```py
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text = "Many studies to date have described the anticancer properties of G. lucidum.  The studies are vast."
print(sent_tokenize(text))

# ['Many studies to date have described the anticancer properties of G. lucidum.', 'The studies are vast.']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't used NLTK yet, but I have used spaCy (although I'm also a novice). According to your prompt, I found that spaCy also has the function of dividing sentences. Thank you for expanding my knowledge.